# fixed header - anchor to input fields

Tags: css, anchor, fixed

My page has a fixed header.

When a user does not pass form validation on form submission I display a list of errors above the form each with a link to the form element that produced the error.

However when I click the link to the anchor the element is hidden by the fixed header.

I have seen a number of css solutions that use pseudo class `:before` to fix this problem, however this cannot be applied to an input element.

Is there an alternative css based solution or am I forced to create a JS work around?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried using a z-index?

Answer (score 0):

The container that has all the error messages you can set the `padding-top` equal to the height of your header. Then it will off-set the list. You will have to play around with the px to get it to look properly. It's not a perfect solution but it's an easy one.

Here's a quick example as you don't have any of your code provided:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    Fixed Header
</div>
<div id="error">
    <ul>
        <li>Error One</li>
        <li>Error Two</li>
        <li>Error Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header { 
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

#error {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Here it is in [jsfiddle form](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9R9Q/). Hopefully I understood the problem correctly.